# Powershell Programming Help needed

Tags: powershell, batch-processing, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I need to create a Powershell Program that read all the .TXT files present in a folder, and process .TXT file one by one to create .WAV files out of that. To convert .TXT to .WAV file we have Azure cloud TTS service command to use it "SPX"  :

```
spx synthesize --files C_F_46044_201806281417.txt;.ssml --audio output 46044.wav
```

My .TXT file is having naming convention like this `C_F_46044_201806281417.txt`, so I need to parse `C`, `F` and `46044` out of that filename, and based on those letter I will move that .WAV file to respective `C` --> `F` folders.
If the file is like `M_E_12345_201806281417.txt` that .WAV file should go to `M` --> `E` folder.
Also, .WAV generated file should rename it as `46044.WAV` or `12345.WAV` based on 3rd parsing.

After .TXT files successfully got processed and converted to .WAV file, we will move file from input location to archive location.

**$Parts[2]  --> I need 46044   from file name  C_F_46044_201806281417.txt**

**Below is the programming logic I have created so far:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$delim = "_"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\rinki\Documents\azure\" -Filter *.txt |
Foreach-Object {

    $parts = $_ -split $delim

    #convert text file to wav cd file
    spx synthesize --file $_  --audio output  C:\messages\audio\$parts[2].wav

    if($parts[0] -match "M") {
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination C:\archive\messages -PassThru
    }

    if($parts[0] -match "C") {
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination C:\archive\competitors -PassThru
    }

    #take a backup of file to another archive location
    #Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination C:\archive\backup -PassThru
}
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  : I have added the program logic that I have created, as requested by you, please help if you know the answer and is expert in Powershell.

Comment: It is not clear where you need to copy the converted files to.. `C --> F folders`. Is `C` the drive and `F` the folder or ??? Your code now copies everything to the same `D:\archive` folder

Comment: @Theo : Both are folder, C and F.

Comment: Folders **where** ?? You need to copy the converted file to both these folders? Do yourself a favor and be more specific. Noone here can see your screen or read your mind.. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70393964/edit) your question and add some real examples, show us where the copies should go

Comment: @Theo   : I have edited, please check, split is not working as expected, not able to parse the input file name based on delimiter "_"  -->  "C"  and "F" and  "46044"

Comment: @Theo   : I am able to solve the issue, parts[2] is now coming, i just need to add varaiable first.    -->   $soundname =  $parts[2] 

    #convert text file to wav cd file
    spx synthesize --file $_  --audio output  C:\messages\audio\$soundname.wav

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer, thanks all for your time:

```
$delim = "_"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\rinki\Documents\azure\" -Filter *.txt |
Foreach-Object {

    $parts = $_ -split $delim

    $soundname =  $parts[2] 

    #convert text file to wav cd file
    spx synthesize --file $_  --audio output  C:\messages\audio\$soundname.wav

    if($parts[0] -match "M") {
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination C:\archive\messages -PassThru
    }

    if($parts[0] -match "C") {
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination C:\archive\competitors -PassThru
    }

    #take a backup of file to another archive location
    #Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination C:\archive\backup -PassThru
}
```